# scikit learn incremental pca confusion

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I have a dataset with (n_samples, n_features) = (466000, 4338093).
I want to perform PCA on this data so utilizing Python's Scikit learn's Incremental PCA.

Since the data is huge, it is split into 466 chunks of 1000 samples each i.e each chunk will have (n_samples, n_features) = (1000, 4338093). Each of the chunk is stored as a hickle file. Also, the matrix is in sparse format.

I have set the n_components of PCA to min(n_samples, n_features) which is 466000.

The following is how I do it for 2 chunks:

```
import hickle
from sklearn.decomposition import IncrementalPCA
import os

fv_list = list()

for file_name in os.listdir("PATH_TO_DIR"):
    if file_name.endswith(".hkl"):
        fv_list.append(os.path.join("PATH_TO_DIR", file_name))

data_shape = hickle.load(open(fv_list[0])).shape
ipca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=min(len(fv_list) * data_shape[0], data_shape[1]))

for each_chunk in fv_list:
    part = hickle.load(open(each_chunk))
    ipca.partial_fit(part.todense())
```

Now, when I call the partial fit method of the pca, for the 2nd iteration I get the following error:

`ValueError: Number of input features has changed from 1000 to 466000 between calls to partial_fit! Try setting n_components to a fixed value.`

I am confused of why this ValueError occurs. Is my approach wrong ?

Comment: Try to use : ipca = IncrementalPCA(n_components=466000) and see if you get the same error

Comment: Try printing the shape of `part.todense()` in 1st and 2nd iteration to see if they actually match or not.

Comment: @VivekKumar: For each iteration the shape is 1000, 4338093.

Comment: @sera: I don't see how it makes a difference but I have tried any way. Still the same error.

Comment: I think that there is something wrong when you iterate for the first time. The n_components you set to 466000 are set to 1000. And in second iteration they are again set to 466000. Please post the full stack trace of error.

Comment: I found this [issue here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6452). Seems like what you are trying to do is not supported, because n_components are greater than the sample size of single batch, and hence ill_defined.